# How to Code Favorites system in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, favorites

i have an application in VB.NET had a form which view videos every video have [Add to Favorites Button] so when the user click on this Button the program will save the video name in a [ListView] in another Form and when the user click on the video name on the ListView will open the video form . 
so how Can i code this system ? 
i try with Registry and .ini and XML but i failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start with the basics. You are trying to create a Video application (Like Popcorn Time) with favorites, which is quiet a task you choose for yourself.

Start with reading tutorials and books about VB.NET and desktop application development. One example would be: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/

You will not be able to produce anything useful unless you understand and master the basics. For example: You want to store favorites, but are missing the concept of how data is stored in an application, what options you have, which should be used when, why certain options fit in your scenario, etc..

You are basically going into the BMW dealers shop saying: Listen so I have wheels and metal, how do I get a car?